# How do I add a follow facebook button to my html

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I'm not a hardcore developer, so please go easy on me :)

I'm building a new website for myself (I'm a designer) and I've tried adding facebook "Follow" and "Like" buttons to my HTML (I'm **not** using a CMS of any kind), by following the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button

I've created an app ID already.

I generate the code (using my own Profile URL), I put the top chunk of generated code immediately after the opening `<body>` tag, and then the bottom chunk of code of generated code somewhere on the page.  I even put "test text here" in the div.

When I save and refresh my web page, all it does is add "test text here", but no follow or like buttons in sight!

I've even tried the code from this page which is slightly different, and have put in my own app ID in the relevant place: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I saw a similar question here which was closed because it was apparently not a real question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261443/facebook-follow-button-html5-dreamweaver

Comment: Anybody else got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3214-Add-the-Twitter-Tweet-and-Follow-Buttons-without-Hiring-a-Developer

Try if this helps you. I don't know what your code looks like but, this should help you a little.

Comment: No good I'm afraid, as that's for Twitter, not facebook.  But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying this code to your webpage and make sure you put the right url to your page directly:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" >
<img src="_images/footer_buttons/facebook.png" />
```

Try downloading a small Facebook button image and add some CSS for the button so that its positioned and sized the way you want it.

CSS example:

```
#bottom_icons img{

border: 1px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
border-radius: 3px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;
margin-left:2px;
margin-top:5px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not quite what I wanted, as it's not an active follow or like button, but I may resort to just putting a button in, as you suggest.  Thanks for the suggestion!